# Synonym for "ready to use"?

Tags: synonyms

What is a good adjective for something that is ready for use, in the sense that it was prepared in advance (besides "ready" or "prepared")?

Example usage: "This (adjective) document is immediately available for your use" or "This file is already ready because it's (adjective)".

Comment: I think your suggestions are appropriate when reworded: "This prepared document is ready for [your] use." "This ready-to-use file." Perhaps you could find a suitable synonym for a specific type of use?

Comment: I agree that prepared is perfectly suitable in this context. I don't think there is a more apt term.

Answer (score 4):

A bit more informally: "good to go", perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

**Readied**, **Primed**, or **Armed**, depending on your context.

Answer (score 2):

How about the word 'readymade' ?
It isn't a verbatim fit. But can be used in quite the same sense.

Answer (score 2):

"pre-processed" or "primed" might fit.

Answer (score 1):

I guess 'All Set' can be used.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be operational.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the past participle form **prepped**. The verb *[prep](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prepped)* means

> to make (someone or something) ready for something

Also consider the phrase **[on deck](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on+deck)**

> ready for duty

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "**ripe**". But it won't fit in your example say "The file is **ripe** for analysis". It doesn't sound good. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

"**[all ready](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/All+ready)**" would fit also.

> ready in every particular; wholly equipped or prepared.

Answer (score 0):

*Bespoke*, but that is a little too U.K.-ish. On the other hand, the Internet is bringing the word across the pond. Also, *custom* document.

You also have:

This *form* document is ready for your use.

You don't even have to use document, the word "precedent" comprehends it.

This *precedent* is ready for your use.

The latter two examples are often seen in legal practice.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a phrase that might be useful, depending on the context, it's "[up and running](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+and+running)".

Comment: First of all, welcome to EL&U! This would be indeed an excellent fit for any form of machinery, contraption, system or electronic device. Unfortunately I doubt it is a fit to the examples given in the main question. Still worth mentioning that it would apply under certain circumstances.

Comment: This answer would be strengthened if it had a link, and a quote from that link, defining "up and running".

Comment: Please improve your answer by doing what Andy T suggests.