# Synonym for "Ready to use" statistics

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a synonym for something like **"ready to use"**. I have found [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151737/synonym-for-ready-to-use) question, but I am not sure if *"prepped"* or *"primed"* are nice solutions for a logo subline.

So my logo subline should be something like **"Ready to use streaming statistics"**. Looking forward receiving your suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: You're entitled to use ready-to-use attributively; this avoids the ambiguity.

Comment: ready-made, ready-to-hand.

Comment: Or, "Readily accessible, streaming statistics." Or, "Streaming statistics which are readily accessible." Or, in imperative mode, "Stream readily available statistics." Don

Comment: What about **ready streaming statistics**?

Answer (score 3):

I've got just the word. See [turnkey](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turnkey) at Merriam Webster, defined by it as

> complete and ready to be used.

You'll have to scroll down, as this is the secondary meaning of the word.

I always forget to mention one important thing. It is that one should opt for a simple word that relays a message easily rather than contracting multiple-word phrases with one word substitutes. Basic communication skills. As pointed out by Edwin below, use *ready to use* instead of fancy words.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this I think that this word and it's meaning is not very well known internationally? What do you think?

Comment: Not just internationally. This word isn't known to many English users as well. I know it because I've memorized most of the words. But one has to settle for a rare word if the concept demands.

Comment: I disagree here. I'd settle for 'ready to use' any day.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree with you. But it's fun to have one around.

Comment: And there's already a turnkey statistics company... http://turnkeywebsolutions.com/Reporting-and-Statistics/

Answer (score 2):

The [phrase](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=out%20of%20the%20box)

> out of the box

implies something that is ready to use, you just have to "open the box" and you have what you need. This is in contrast to something that requires a lot of configuration.

However the phrase "thinking outside the box" is used to mean thinking thoughts in an unconstrained and innovative manner.

Another [option](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/off-the-shelf)  is

> off the shelf

which implies that something is ready and waiting to be used. Again there is no need to wait while it is adapted for particular use.

In the garment industry

> off the peg (or off the rack)

refers to a garment you can simply  collect and wear, in contrast to a bespoke, or tailor-made, garment which is made specifically for the customer.